# Visual Studio Code Tasks Don't Have Environment Variables SEt

Tags: bash, visual-studio-code

I need to run a VS Code task that uses the UID of the user running the task. I created the following task:

```
    {
        "type": "shell",
        "label": "env variable",
        "options": {
            "shell": {
              "args": ["-c", "-p","-l"]
            }
        },
        "command":["echo"],
        "args": [
            "shell ",
            "${env:SHELL}",
            " username ",
            "${env:USER}",
            " homedir",
            "${env:HOME}",
            " uid: ",
            "${env:UID}",
            " gid: ",
            "${env:GID}"
        ]
    }
```

Running this task I get:

```
> Executing task: echo 'shell ' /usr/bin/bash ' username ' gperez ' homedir' /home/gperez ' uid: '  ' gid: '  <

shell  /usr/bin/bash  username  gperez  homedir /home/gperez  uid:   gid:
```

For some reason a subset of my env variables are okay like USER and HOME, but UID and GID are inexplicably not set!

Anyone know how to fix this?

BTW, running echo $UID from the terminal provided by VS Code has UID and GID set no problem!

Answer (score 1):

try...

1. without env: on this two
2. add optional "problemMatcher": [],

Like

```
enter code here
        "type": "shell",
        "problemMatcher": [],
        "label": "env variable",
        "options": {
            "shell": {
              "args": ["-c", "-p","-l"]
            }
        },
        "command":["echo"],
        "args": [
            "shell ",
            "${env:SHELL}",
            " username ",
            "${env:USER}",
            " homedir",
            "${env:HOME}",
            " uid: ",
            "${UID}",
            " gid: ",
            "${GID}"
        ]
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).